# How format string array in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I edit AzureTemplate.XAML . On Arguments I created **ServiceName** and set Argument type: String []. In workflow I set

```
String.Format("-ServiceName {0}",ServiceName)
```

But in Powershell this ServiceName set as String[] instead of array. So how it's fixed?

Comment: A String[] is an array of strings, is ServiceName a single string or a collection of strings?

Comment: Does it contain multiple strings?

Comment: yes. It is usual array: string[]

Comment: Try String.Format("-ServiceName {0}", String.Join(", ", ServiceName))